# DateTime Format Hour Plus One

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, formatting

I'm working with a DataGridView and I have a format for the date time column applied like this...

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM\\/dd @ hh:mm tt";
```

I would like to change the format so that it produces something like `07/31 11->12`. 11 being the current hour, and 12 being the next hour. I tried doing `hh+1` and `{hh+1}`. Is there some way to format it like this? Or some way I could override the rendering of the `"Date"` column, but still keep it's type as `DateTime`?

Comment: I can't see any way to custom the date-time to produce that output. Would another date column be too much of a pain?

Comment: Maybe just edit time source before you bind it to datagridview?

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to edit the field before being bounded you could achive what you want this way.

```
  var date = DateTime.Now;

  var customDate = string.Format("{0}->{1}", date.ToString("MM\\/dd hh"), date.AddHours(1).ToString("hh"));
  Console.WriteLine(customDate);
```

Ouputs 07/31 03->04

```
public class SpecialDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
       var date = (DateTime)value;
       return string.Format("{0}->{1}", date.ToString("MM\\/dd hh"), date.AddHours(1).ToString("hh"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I think the other part of the answer is that you can't keep this custom string AND keep it as a DateTime object. It might make sense to create converter functions to seemlessly jump back and forth between the custom string and a valid DateTime.

Comment: This won't work for the application I'm using. It need to be done on a DataGridView, and I want to maintain the original DateTime value for the column.

Comment: @druciferre What type of application framework are you using? You might want to do what Shawn suggested in his comment and use a IValueConverter if possible.

Comment: I went ahead and added an example using IValueConverter.

Comment: The IValueConverter looks promising, but how do I implement it as the DataGridView format?